# How to run other tests in TestNG after Assertion failure

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using TestNG to kick off Selenium test suites and handle all my logging of my results in a maven project which are being run nightly on a Jenkins job.

Currently when a test fails an assertion, TestNG kills everything we are running, it doesn't just fail the current test and continue running the other tests in the suite. I don't understand why TestNG doesn't just fail the current test and then kick off the remaining tests that have yet to be run. This makes TestNG at this point a useless tool. There has to be a way to configure TestNG somewhere to continue running tests after a single test fails.

And yes I have been looking for answers and I haven't found one to solve this problem yet. I'm starting to think I need to look at a different tool to handle my test execution and results if I can't get TestNG to work properly.

Comment: Are you asserting any conditions in a configuration method? If configuration method fail, TestNG does not invoke any tests.

Answer (score 0):

Make a a helper class for your asserts. Put your assert in a try and catch, when your assert fails, just log the error and do not throw it. In the end of the test, see if there are any errors logged and throw an exception if errors are present

```
public static void AssertVerticalAlignment(int a, int b)
{
    try
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        LogHelper.LogException(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to tear you apart, but TestNG is a Java testing Library, not C# :P this is C#